# Python NetCDF: I/O failure python

Tags: python, netcdf

I try to read a NetCDF file from an OpenDAP-server with Python, but when I convert the time variable I get an I/O failure. The error appears at different steps of the loop and always following values exist and are valid.

The error message is:

```
   nc_time.append(netcdftime.DateFromJulianDay(variable[i]+refjulday,calendar='gregorian'))
File "netCDF4.pyx", line 3064, in netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4.c:42706)
File "netCDF4.pyx", line 3717, in netCDF4.Variable._get (netCDF4.c:50959)
RuntimeError: NetCDF: I/O failure
```

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import netcdftime
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta as td


# Read data from an opendap server
import netCDF4
url = 'http://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov:80/dods/GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H'
# create a dataset object
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(url)

variable = dataset.variables['time']
nc_n_times = variable.shape[0]
print(nc_n_times)
nc_time = []
reftime = datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
refjulday = netcdftime.JulianDayFromDate(reftime, calendar='standard')
for i in range(0, nc_n_times-1):
  nc_time.append(netcdftime.DateFromJulianDay(variable[i]+refjulday,calendar='gregorian'))

print ("done")
```

What is the problem here ?

Many thanks in advance !

Klemens

Comment: Is any of this calendar conversion logic necessary to reproduce the error?  If you just do `print(dataset.variables['time'][:])` or something similar, are you getting the error?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Spencer. Trying it yesterday even trying your statement was not possible, but today everything works fine.